# Working region of NPN BJT

Tags: transistors, analog, bjt, current-source, npn

I have come across the following circuit where a BJT works as switch when I apply 23 volts to base using a 100k resistor.

A 3.2 mA constant current source is connected to the collector of the BJT and that current flows when the base current is present. From the practical observations, the BJT seems to be in saturation mode (Vce_SAT=0.1V.)

How can I mathematically prove that the transistor is in saturation modr? How can I relate that VCE<0.7 Volts mathematically?

[image]

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: A little bit of initial hint would  really be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Search web, Common emitter to a very common question

Comment: What base current is needed to saturate the transistor if Ic = 3.2mA. What base current is flowing in your circuit? Is this current is enough to saturate the transistor?

Comment: You can't mathematically prove the transistor is in saturation. Even by making assumptions and having specific modeling parameters in hand and specific operational details into which all of this can be deduced. Even with all that, it isn't a mathematical proof. But it might be considered as making a good engineering argument.

Comment: For beta of 20, given 230 uA into the base, and 3,200 uA into the collector, the Vce is rather low. To prove the collector_base diode is forward biased (the definition of saturation), is another task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

23 = 100K * Ib + 0.7

Ib = 223 uA

Ic = Beta * Ib = 200 * 223uA = 44.6mA

Verdict:

A base current is enought to switch even 44.6 mA, not only 3.2mA